# How do you use `scanimage` to scan two sides of a document with an adf scanner?

Tags: scanner

I have an ScanSnap iX500 and I'm trying to figure out how to scan two sides of a document with it. Obviously, I need to scan one side, flip the paper and scan the other side. But, I can't figure out how to get `scanimage` to hold up for one second while I flip and reload the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Simple Scan (Comes pre-loaded) to scan the image, once you have done one side, simply flip it over then scan the other part.

Answer (score -1):

Per the man page, it looks like you can use --batch-prompt.  You may need to also add -b

--batch-prompt will tell scanimage to stop after a page is scanned and wait for you to tell it to continue.